# ffmpeg - fit multiple lines of text (having different fonts) with auto line wrap and auto font size?

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, imagemagick

Trying to keep this question to a minimum as in terms of info. Sorry if it's too long and thank you for reading it!

I'm trying to make these texts fit (they have different fonts and font sizes) to the right of the avatar image but having difficulties doing it. The output is an m3u8 playlist file that gets played by a front-end JS video player. Please see the current output: https://postimg.cc/nXx34z96. This command is generated by a Node.js controller (that's why you can find multiple drawtext filters in it, those come from a for loop) and due to privacy I can't copy paste it here.

**Question**: is there any way we can render all text copies, no matter what their font families and font sizes are, for all the three texts:

- without text being cut/missing
- newlines being auto-added
- and the font size auto scaled

so that the text will fit on maximum 2 lines per each? Let's assume a number of maximum X chars per each line based on font-family (there are fonts whose glyphs are wider than others).

Any feedback/direction is greatly appreciated! Thank you much!

**Graphic sketch needed can be found below.**

```
           line1-with-font1
           line2-with-font1(-if-needed)

[avatar]   line1-with-font2
[ here ]   line2-with-font2(-if-needed)

           line1-with-font3
           line2-with-font3(-if-needed)
```

I've also tried writing texts to an image with a transparent background (so I could overlay that into the video afterwards) but I'm having troubles with the png image having the text too blurry (used imagemagick's `convert` and played with different settings).

**Current command**

```
time ffmpeg -y -i 5e47a1be4df117b7f79596dda7987c45.mp4 -i avatar.png -i ../../preview/helper-videos/bokeh.mp4 -i 1629885277.mp3 -preset ultrafast -crf 18 -filter_complex " [0:v]scale=878:494:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=878:494:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,format=yuva420p[video]; [video]fade=in :0 :25[video]; [2:v]scale=1756:988:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.2[motionOverlay];[video][motionOverlay]overlay[video]; [video]drawbox= x=0 :y=0 :w=iw :h=ih :color=0x000000@0.3 :t='fill' :enable='between(t,3,21)'[video]; [1:v]scale=-2:247:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,format=yuva420p[scaledCoverPhoto]; [video][scaledCoverPhoto]overlay=:x=w/2:y=(H-h)/2:enable='between(t,4,21)' ,drawtext=fontfile=../../preview/fonts/opensans-regular.ttf\n` +
"              :text='Main text here, could be long enough to split in multiple lines'\n" +
'              :fontcolor=0xFFFFFF\n' +
'              :fontsize=40\n' +
"              :alpha='\n" +
'              \n' +
"              if(lt(t,5),0,if(lt(t,6),(t-5)/1,if(lt(t,22),1,if(lt(t,28),(1-(t-27))/1,0))))'\n" +
'              :x=W/2\n' +
'              :y=h/2-120, drawtext=fontfile=../../preview/fonts/greatvibes-regular.ttf\n' +
"            :text='This is'\n" +
'            :fontcolor=0xFFFFFF\n' +
'            :fontsize=46\n' +
"            :alpha='if(lt(t,5),0,if(lt(t,7),(t-5)/1,if(lt(t,22),1,if(lt(t,28),(1-(t-27))/1,0))))'\n" +
'                :x=(w-text_w)/2 + 100\n' +
'                :y=200 - text_h/2,drawtext=fontfile=../../preview/fonts/greatvibes-regular.ttf\n' +
"            :text='the title'\n" +
'            :fontcolor=0xFFFFFF\n' +
'            :fontsize=46\n' +
"            :alpha='if(lt(t,5),0,if(lt(t,7),(t-5)/1,if(lt(t,22),1,if(lt(t,28),(1-(t-27))/1,0))))'\n" +
'                :x=(w-text_w)/2 + 100\n' +
'                :y=250 - text_h/2,drawtext=fontfile=../../preview/fonts/greatvibes-regular.ttf\n' +
"            :text='that can'\n" +
'            :fontcolor=0xFFFFFF\n' +
'            :fontsize=46\n' +
"            :alpha='if(lt(t,5),0,if(lt(t,7),(t-5)/1,if(lt(t,22),1,if(lt(t,28),(1-(t-27))/1,0))))'\n" +
'                :x=(w-text_w)/2 + 100\n' +
'                :y=300 - text_h/2,drawtext=fontfile=../../preview/fonts/greatvibes-regular.ttf\n' +
"            :text='be long'\n" +
'            :fontcolor=0xFFFFFF\n' +
'            :fontsize=46\n' +
"            :alpha='if(lt(t,5),0,if(lt(t,7),(t-5)/1,if(lt(t,22),1,if(lt(t,28),(1-(t-27))/1,0))))'\n" +
'                :x=(w-text_w)/2 + 100\n' +
'                :y=350 - text_h/2,drawtext=fontfile=../../preview/fonts/greatvibes-regular.ttf\n' +
"            :text='enough'\n" +
'            :fontcolor=0xFFFFFF\n' +
'            :fontsize=46\n' +
"            :alpha='if(lt(t,5),0,if(lt(t,7),(t-5)/1,if(lt(t,22),1,if(lt(t,28),(1-(t-27))/1,0))))'\n" +
'                :x=(w-text_w)/2 + 100\n' +
'                :y=400 - text_h/2,drawtext=fontfile=../../preview/fonts/greatvibes-regular.ttf\n' +
"            :text='too'\n" +
'            :fontcolor=0xFFFFFF\n' +
'            :fontsize=46\n' +
"            :alpha='if(lt(t,5),0,if(lt(t,7),(t-5)/1,if(lt(t,22),1,if(lt(t,28),(1-(t-27))/1,0))))'\n" +
'                :x=(w-text_w)/2 + 100\n' +
'                :y=450 - text_h/2, drawtext=fontfile=../../preview/fonts/opensans-regular.ttf\n' +
"          :text='A subtitle here, can be long, also'\n" +
'          :fontcolor=0xFFFFFF\n' +
'          :fontsize=20\n' +
"          :alpha='if(lt(t,5),0,if(lt(t,8),(t-5)/1,if(lt(t,22),1,if(lt(t,28),(1-(t-27))/1,0))))'\n" +
'              :x=(w-text_w)/2 + 120\n' +
'              :y=(h-text_h)/2 + text_h*2 + 180, format=yuv420p, scale=-2:494 " -shortest -map 3:a -format hls -sn -hls_time 5 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_flags split_by_time -hls_playlist_type event -g 4 -r 25 output/index.m3u8'
```

**Command output**

```
LOG: [
'INFO',
'stderr:',
'ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers\n' +
'  built with Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)\n' +
'  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox\n' +
'  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100\n' +
'  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100\n' +
'  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100\n' +
'  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100\n' +
'  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100\n' +
'  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0\n' +
'  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100\n' +
'  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100\n' +
'  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100\n' +
"Input #0, image2, from '07201487ede265cdea98d02930cd90dd.jpg':\n" +
'  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 62761 kb/s\n' +
'  Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 411x494 [SAR 96:96 DAR 411:494], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc\n' +
'Stream mapping:\n' +
'  Stream #0:0 (mjpeg) -> scale\n' +
'  fade -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)\n' +
'Press [q] to stop, [?] for help\n' +
'[swscaler @ 0x7fceb8008000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fceb3809400] using SAR=411/494\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fceb3809400] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fceb3809400] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 1.0, 4:4:4, 8-bit\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fceb3809400] 264 - core 163 r3060 5db6aa6 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00\n' +
"Output #0, mp4, to 'coverPhoto-35034893880715867923.mp4':\n" +
'  Metadata:\n' +
'    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100\n' +
'  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown, progressive), 100x100 [SAR 411:494 DAR 411:494], q=2-31, 25 fps, 12800 tbn\n' +
'    Metadata:\n' +
'      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 libx264\n' +
'    Side data:\n' +
'      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A\n' +
'frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    \rframe=  102 fps=0.0 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.08 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s speed=4.14x    \rframe=  200 fps=199 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:06.00 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed=5.96x    \rframe=  327 fps=217 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:11.08 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=7.35x    \rframe=  456 fps=227 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:16.24 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=8.08x    \rframe=  475 fps=225 q=-1.0 Lsize=      32kB time=00:00:18.88 bitrate=  13.7kbits/s speed=8.95x    \n' +
'video:25kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 25.380770%\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fceb3809400] frame I:3     Avg QP:14.28  size:  3258\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fceb3809400] frame P:120   Avg QP:23.93  size:    91\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fceb3809400] frame B:352   Avg QP:33.22  size:    13\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fceb3809400] consecutive B-frames:  1.1%  0.0%  1.3% 97.7%\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fceb3809400] mb I  I16..4:  2.0% 58.5% 39.5%\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fceb3809400] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.1%  P16..4:  5.5%  0.6%  0.8%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:93.0%\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fceb3809400] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.2%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.8%  L0: 0.0% L1:93.1% BI: 6.9%\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fceb3809400] 8x8 transform intra:56.2% inter:44.5%\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fceb3809400] coded y,u,v intra: 58.3% 48.0% 46.2% inter: 1.0% 0.7% 0.7%\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fceb3809400] i16 v,h,dc,p:  0%  0% 100%  0%\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fceb3809400] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  6%  5% 72%  3%  3%  3%  2%  3%  3%\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fceb3809400] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 21% 23% 10%  6%  9%  6%  7%  7% 11%\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fceb3809400] Weighted P-Frames: Y:6.7% UV:6.7%\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fceb3809400] ref P L0: 93.6%  2.7%  2.0%  1.7%\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fceb3809400] ref B L1: 96.6%  3.4%\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fceb3809400] kb/s:10.57\n' +
'ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers\n' +
'  built with Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)\n' +
'  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox\n' +
'  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100\n' +
'  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100\n' +
'  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100\n' +
'  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100\n' +
'  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100\n' +
'  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0\n' +
'  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100\n' +
'  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100\n' +
'  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100\n' +
"Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '5e47a1be4df117b7f79596dda7987c45.mp4':\n" +
'  Metadata:\n' +
'    major_brand     : isom\n' +
'    minor_version   : 512\n' +
'    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41\n' +
'    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100\n' +
'    media_type      : 0\n' +
'    hd_video        : 0\n' +
'  Duration: 00:00:21.29, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1139 kb/s\n' +
'  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 878x494 [SAR 3952:3951 DAR 16:9], 1136 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 48 tbc (default)\n' +
'    Metadata:\n' +
'      handler_name    : VideoHandler\n' +
'      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]\n' +
"Input #1, png_pipe, from '07201487ede265cdea98d02930cd90dd.jpg.png':\n" +
'  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A\n' +
'  Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 431x514 [SAR 3779:3779 DAR 431:514], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc\n' +
"Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '../../preview/helper-videos/bokeh.mp4':\n" +
'  Metadata:\n' +
'    major_brand     : mp42\n' +
'    minor_version   : 0\n' +
'    compatible_brands: isommp42\n' +
'    creation_time   : 2012-03-21T12:18:56.000000Z\n' +
'  Duration: 00:00:07.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1060 kb/s\n' +
'  Stream #2:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1152x720, 1054 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 50 tbn, 50 tbc (default)\n' +
'    Metadata:\n' +
'      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z\n' +
'      handler_name    : VideoHandler\n' +
'      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]\n' +
'  Stream #2:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 3 kb/s (default)\n' +
'    Metadata:\n' +
'      creation_time   : 2012-03-21T12:18:56.000000Z\n' +
'      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011\n' +
'      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]\n' +
"Input #3, mp3, from '1629885277.mp3':\n" +
'  Metadata:\n' +
'    title           : The Gift of Love\n' +
'    TLEN            : 228773\n' +
'    publisher       : Musical Reflections, Inc.\n' +
'    genre           : Instrumental\n' +
"    album           : Love's Journey\n" +
'    album_artist    : Tami Briggs\n' +
'    track           : 7\n' +
'    artist          : Tami Briggs\n' +
'    date            : 1999-00-00\n' +
'    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100\n' +
'    id3v2_priv.WM/MediaClassPrimaryID: \\xbc}`\\xd1#\\xe3\\xe2K\\x86\\xa1H\\xa4*(D\\x1e\n' +
'    id3v2_priv.WM/MediaClassSecondaryID: \\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\n' +
'    id3v2_priv.WM/WMContentID: \\xee\\xb1,V\\xa5H*A\\x9c\\x07\\xbb/\\xbb3\\xc2\\xba\n' +
'    id3v2_priv.WM/UniqueFileIdentifier: A\\x00M\\x00G\\x00a\\x00_\\x00i\\x00d\\x00=\\x00R\\x00 \\x00 \\x00 \\x007\\x007\\x003\\x003\\x008\\x008\\x00;\\x00A\\x00M\\x00G\\x00p\\x00_\\x00i\\x00d\\x00=\\x00P\\x00 \\x00 \\x00 \\x007\\x000\\x007\\x000\\x009\\x004\\x00;\\x00A\\x00M\\x00G\\x00t\\x00_\\x00i\\x00d\\x00=\\x00T\\x00 \\x00 \\x007\\x008\\x00\n' +
'    id3v2_priv.WM/WMCollectionID: (\\xc2\\xd0\\x91\\x17\\xa1rK\\xa3\\xfd\\xea\\xe6QBA\\x81\n' +
'    id3v2_priv.WM/WMCollectionGroupID: (\\xc2\\xd0\\x91\\x17\\xa1rK\\xa3\\xfd\\xea\\xe6QBA\\x81\n' +
'    id3v2_priv.WM/Provider: A\\x00M\\x00G\\x00\\x00\\x00\n' +
'    id3v2_priv.XMP  : <?xpacket begin="\\xef\\xbb\\xbf" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>\\x0a<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.6-c014 79.156821, 2014/08/29-03:07:50        ">\\x0a <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">\\x0a  <rdf\n' +
'  Duration: 00:03:44.21, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 128 kb/s\n' +
'  Stream #3:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s\n' +
'    Metadata:\n' +
'      encoder         : Lavc58.54\n' +
'Codec AVOption format (set pixel type) specified for output file #0 (output/index.m3u8) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.\n' +
'Stream mapping:\n' +
'  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> scale (graph 0)\n' +
'  Stream #1:0 (png) -> scale (graph 0)\n' +
'  Stream #2:0 (h264) -> scale (graph 0)\n' +
'  scale (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)\n' +
'  Stream #3:0 -> #0:1 (mp3 (mp3float) -> aac (native))\n' +
'Press [q] to stop, [?] for help\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fd66c813400] using SAR=1/1\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fd66c813400] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fd66c813400] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fd66c813400] 264 - core 163 r3060 5db6aa6 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=15 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=4 keyint_min=1 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=18.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0\n' +
"Output #0, hls, to 'output/index.m3u8':\n" +
'  Metadata:\n' +
'    major_brand     : isom\n' +
'    minor_version   : 512\n' +
'    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41\n' +
'    hd_video        : 0\n' +
'    media_type      : 0\n' +
'    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100\n' +
'  Stream #0:0: Video: h264, yuv420p(tv, progressive), 878x494 [SAR 1:1 DAR 439:247], q=2-31, 25 fps, 90k tbn (default)\n' +
'    Metadata:\n' +
'      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 libx264\n' +
'    Side data:\n' +
'      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A\n' +
'  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s\n' +
'    Metadata:\n' +
'      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 aac\n' +
"frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    \rframe=   26 fps=0.0 q=19.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.40 bitrate=N/A dup=1 drop=0 speed=0.677x    \rframe=   55 fps= 50 q=14.0 size=N/A time=00:00:01.56 bitrate=N/A dup=2 drop=0 speed=1.41x    \rframe=   82 fps= 51 q=15.0 size=N/A time=00:00:02.64 bitrate=N/A dup=3 drop=0 speed=1.63x    \rframe=  104 fps= 49 q=19.0 size=N/A time=00:00:03.52 bitrate=N/A dup=4 drop=0 speed=1.64x    \rframe=  129 fps= 49 q=17.0 size=N/A time=00:00:04.52 bitrate=N/A dup=5 drop=0 speed= 1.7x    \r[hls @ 0x7fd66c80ba00] Opening 'output/index0.ts' for writing\n" +
"[hls @ 0x7fd66c80ba00] Opening 'output/index.m3u8.tmp' for writing\n" +
"frame=  150 fps= 47 q=16.0 size=N/A time=00:00:05.36 bitrate=N/A dup=6 drop=0 speed=1.69x    \rframe=  169 fps= 46 q=18.0 size=N/A time=00:00:06.12 bitrate=N/A dup=7 drop=0 speed=1.66x    \rframe=  227 fps= 54 q=15.0 size=N/A time=00:00:08.44 bitrate=N/A dup=9 drop=0 speed=2.02x    \r[hls @ 0x7fd66c80ba00] Opening 'output/index1.ts' for writing\n" +
"[hls @ 0x7fd66c80ba00] Opening 'output/index.m3u8.tmp' for writing\n" +
"frame=  280 fps= 60 q=20.0 size=N/A time=00:00:10.56 bitrate=N/A dup=11 drop=0 speed=2.25x    \rframe=  342 fps= 66 q=17.0 size=N/A time=00:00:13.04 bitrate=N/A dup=14 drop=0 speed=2.51x    \r[hls @ 0x7fd66c80ba00] Opening 'output/index2.ts' for writing\n" +
"[hls @ 0x7fd66c80ba00] Opening 'output/index.m3u8.tmp' for writing\n" +
"frame=  410 fps= 72 q=18.0 size=N/A time=00:00:15.76 bitrate=N/A dup=16 drop=0 speed=2.76x    \rframe=  490 fps= 79 q=16.0 size=N/A time=00:00:18.96 bitrate=N/A dup=20 drop=0 speed=3.06x    \r[hls @ 0x7fd66c80ba00] Opening 'output/index3.ts' for writing\n" +
"[hls @ 0x7fd66c80ba00] Opening 'output/index.m3u8.tmp' for writing\n" +
"[hls @ 0x7fd66c80ba00] Opening 'output/index4.ts' for writing\n" +
"[hls @ 0x7fd66c80ba00] Opening 'output/index.m3u8.tmp' for writing\n" +
'frame=  532 fps= 82 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:21.28 bitrate=N/A dup=21 drop=0 speed=3.29x    \n' +
'video:11798kB audio:333kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fd66c813400] frame I:133   Avg QP:14.64  size: 68603\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fd66c813400] frame P:399   Avg QP:17.71  size:  7410\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fd66c813400] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fd66c813400] mb P  I16..4:  9.8%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 28.5%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:61.7%\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fd66c813400] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 58.0% 41.2% 27.3% inter: 16.6% 7.9% 0.1%\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fd66c813400] i16 v,h,dc,p: 36% 28% 18% 18%\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fd66c813400] i8c dc,h,v,p: 61% 20% 14%  6%\n' +
'[libx264 @ 0x7fd66c813400] kb/s:4541.68\n' +
'[aac @ 0x7fd66c820400] Qavg: 931.453\n' +
'\n' +
'real\t0m6.605s\n' +
'user\t0m16.878s\n' +
'sys\t0m0.465s'
]
```

Comment: Best option is ASS or SRT subtitles with the [subtitles filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles).

Comment: Thank you @llogan! I'm thinking to dynamically create/write an .ass file that I'll send over to the ffmpeg command. Are there any other alternatives? The videos are generated on the fly with dynamic texts.

Comment: With ffmpeg only drawtext or subtitles/ass filters.